# Aspx control are not visible in cs file

Tags: asp.net

I upload 2 page and downloaded same page.I added 2 more control in that file.But my aspx page control are not visible in my .cs file.When I am compling it,error occur on cs file(ddlbrand is not exist in current context).I am using vs 2005.I don't have designer file.(Only aspx and cs file).

Comment: please give the code for real help. You probably have not formatted correct.

Answer (score 1):

Check if your controls are well formed, if the problem exists than I think you can't do that without the whole project and the solution file. You need to make changes in the project with visual studio. All the controls you add in the page are also added to the designer file.

Web Application Projects compile the .CS files as part of the build, and compile the ASPX's on the fly referencing your pre-built codebehind DLL - that's why you have to recompile if you change the code behind.

Answer (score 0):

No designer file means you are working in ASP.Net Website project.

Check your aspx markup it must be missing some closing tag or some important parameter like `runat="server"`

Comment: control has runat= server property.

Comment: then check for closing tags. how many lines do you have in markup?

Comment: I checked, all tag close properly.